# Get Checkbox Values from Forms using an External PHP Processor

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have a form that sends its data to a process.php file for processing in that file I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $number = $_GET['number'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $comment = $_GET['message'];
    $sales = $_POST['sales'];
    $lettings = $_POST['lettings'];

    $to = "me@me.com";

    $subject = "New website registration";

    $message = "Name: ".$name."\r\n";
    if(isset($number) && $number!='')
        $message.= "Number: ".$number."\r\n";
    if(isset($email) && $email!='')
        $message.= "Email: ".$email."\r\n";
    if(isset($comment) && $comment!='')
        $message.= "Comment: ".$comment."\r\n";
    if(isset($sales))
    {
        $message.= "I am Interested in Sales" . "\r\n";
    }else{
        //
    }
    if(isset($lettings))
    {
        $message.= "I am Interested in Lettings";
    }else{
        //
    }

    $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">";

    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    return $result;
?>
```

The HTML for the form is as follows:

```
<form id="register_form" name="register" method="post" action="/content/contact/process.php">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="regform" onFocus="if(this.value=='Name'){this.value='';}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Name';}" value="Name" />
    <input type="text" id="number" name="number" class="regform" onFocus="if(this.value=='Phone number'){this.value='';}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Phone number';}" value="Phone number" />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="regform" onFocus="if(this.value=='Email address'){this.value='';}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Email address';}" value="Email address" />
    <textarea id="message" name="message" class="regtext" onFocus="if(this.value=='Message'){this.value='';}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Message';}">Message</textarea>
    <label for"sales">Sales<input type="checkbox" name="sales" value="1" /></label>
    <label for"sales">Lettings<input type="checkbox" name="lettings" value="1"/></label>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="regsender" />
    <div class="loading"></div>
</form>
```

When the checkboxes are checked, the expected messages do not come through in the email. Am I missing something here. I've tried several different approaches to getting this to work, none of which do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @ register_form youre using method post, but @ php youre using $_GET? have you tried $_POST, CMIIW

Comment: Yes, tried both but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using method = POST and retrieving values with $_GET

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code check it

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $number = $_POST['number'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $comment = $_POST['message'];
        if (isset($_POST['sales'])) 
        {
            $sales = $_POST['sales'];
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['lettings']))
        {
            $lettings =$_POST['lettings'];
        }

        $to = "me@me.com";

        $subject = "New website registration";

        $message = "Name: ".$name."\r\n";
        if(isset($number) && $number!='')
            $message.= "Number: ".$number."\r\n";
        if(isset($email) && $email!='')
            $message.= "Email: ".$email."\r\n";
        if(isset($comment) && $comment!='')
            $message.= "Comment: ".$comment."\r\n";

        if(isset($_POST['sales']))
        {
            $message.= "I am Interested in Sales" . "\r\n";
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['lettings']))
        {
            $message.= "I am Interested in Lettings";
        }
        echo $message;
        $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">";

        $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

        return $result;
      }
    ?>

<form id="register_form" name="register" method="post" action="testing_page.php">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="regform" onFocus="if(this.value=='Name'){this.value='';}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Name';}" value="Name" />
    <input type="text" id="number" name="number" class="regform" onFocus="if(this.value=='Phone number'){this.value='';}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Phone number';}" value="Phone number" />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="regform" onFocus="if(this.value=='Email address'){this.value='';}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Email address';}" value="Email address" />
    <textarea id="message" name="message" class="regtext" onFocus="if(this.value=='Message'){this.value='';}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Message';}">Message</textarea>
    <label for"sales">Sales<input type="checkbox" name="sales" value="1" /></label>
    <label for"sales">Lettings<input type="checkbox" name="lettings" value="1"/></label>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="regsender" />
    <div class="loading"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: All other values come through fine using $_GET in the external process.php file except for the checkboxes. If I change the values from $_GET to $_POST in process.php nothing comes through at all?

Comment: The PHP code that processes the form is in an external file and not part of the form.

Comment: Use $_POST['sales'] for checkbox only and check it

Comment: I've amended the code above using $_POST instead of $_GET but it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the email to my correct email and added your code but now no email comes through?

Comment: Ok remove all echo and check it again then after it does not work then    you can need to configure mail smtp account using php ini_set()

Comment: Why do I need to setup mail smtp account using php ini_set()? The email was working previously just not bringing through the checkboxes?

Comment: Ok then try this code $headers = "From: ".$name." ".$email; otherwise remove name and use email only

Comment: That's simply to set the From email address, which was working. The actual email doesn't arrive?